# Replacing classnames in several files

Tags: javascript, css, angular

A question seem to be pretty simple, still I can't find an anwer. I'm doing migration from one design system to another (in an Angular project if that matter). That means I need to replace classnames all over the project. Are there any vscode extensions to deal with that? Maybe it's better to develop a script for that? An example of such a script is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without an extension:

Click the search icon in VSCode and you will see 2 input bars, the one at the top is to put the current class name, bottom with placeholder as "Repalce" is the new name you want it to have. The files should be in one folder, so you can choose which files to include or exclude.

Click here for a visual: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFv0n.png)

To replace all classes in one click:
[image]

Comment: Yes, it's a solution. But I'm searching a way to replace dozens of classes, not a single class at a time

Comment: Oh easy, you click on this button, it means "Repalce All" Check screenshot in edited post.

Comment: @Eugeny89 use regex with `|` separated classnames you want to replace

Comment: @mandy8055, looks like that will replace N different classes with a single one, while I need to replace N classes with N another classes

Comment: @Eugeny89 provide me some classnames on some sample data in your question I can help you with the regex.